# Changing google app script web app into php website

Tags: php, mysql, google-apps-script

I have a web app developed using Google App Script. I just want to that if I changed the database from google sheets into mysql database is it possible to change my google app script coding into php language coding?

Comment: LAMP is a very common sort of website.  There are probably many more such sites then there are webapps so yes I would say it would be possible to rewrite your code so that you could utilize mySQL and php.

Comment: It depends what the script does exactly, but maybe. Since we know nothing about it, it's difficult to give any kind of definite answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a language different than Apps Script, then obviously, you can't use the built-in services, you'd need to use the Google API's.  So, for example, if you want to send an email, you'd need to use the Google Gmail API.

See:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api

Also, you'd need a hosting service.  If you want to stay with Google produces for hosting your website, then you would use App Engine.
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php

You could also use Firebase Hosting, but you can't use PHP with Firebase Hosting.  There are other languages that you can use for server code for a website.